# how to call an android specific code in an event handler

Tags: c#, xamarin

Being new in the Xamarin environment, I didn't succeed calling correctly an Android specific class.

in the Android section of my solution I have created the following class for getting the phone's own number:

```
[Service]
        public class PhoneNr : IntentService
        {       
           public string ownNumber;
            protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
            {
                var telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);               
                ownNumber =telephonyManager.Line1Number; 
           }             
        }
```

On my general main page, I want to execute this class through the event handler of a button, but of course in such way, that it will only activate when the phone is an Android.
So that would be something similar to:

```
private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if phone = android
            PhoneNr p = new PhoneNr();
        label.txt = p.ownNumber;
       }
```

Anyone who can tell me how to implement this correctly in the button's event handler so that:
1: the class PhoneNr is recognized within the event handler
2: execution only if the phone is an Android

Thanks a lot,

Comment: use the Xamarin Forms DependencyService to call platform specific code

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Answer (score 0):

To check the device use the below code:

```
private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android){
       PhoneNr p = new PhoneNr();
       label.txt = p.ownNumber;
    }
}
```

The service you have needs to be setup as a dependency service. This is well documented and can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Below is a simple example for you. If you actually create a dependency service in all platforms you don't have to check the device OS.

```
       //Interface should be in its own file. 
   public interface IPhoneNR{
        String getOwnerNumber();
   }

   //assembly, register dependency
   [assembly: Dependency (typeof (PhoneNr))]
   namespace AndroidAppPCL
   {
        public class PhoneNr : IPhoneNR
        {       
        public string ownNumber;
            protected String getOwnerNumber()
            {
                var telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);               
                return telephonyManager.Line1Number; 
            }             
        }
    }

    //Use in code PCL
    private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android){
            label.txt = DependencyService.Get<IPhoneNR>().getOwnerNumber();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. I tried your code, but with the ": IntentService" inheritance left out, I get errors in my  ApplicationContext.GetSystemService() part.   Maybe something to do with the fact I have the latest version of Visual Studio whereas docs.microsoft states that: "Portable Class Libraries (PCLs) are considered deprecated in the latest versions of Visual Studio" ?

Comment: According to the Xamarin documentation, "While you can still open, edit, and compile PCLs, for new projects it is recommended to use .NET Standard libraries to access a larger API surface area." You should not get an error on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally gotten rid of all errors, using both DependencyService ass well as IntentService, however not yet tested on a physical Android phone.
I leave the code below in case other people are having the same problem.

Android part:

```
public class Personalia_android : IPersonalia
    {


        public string getOwnNr()
        {
            PhoneNr p = new PhoneNr();
            return(p.getOwnNumber());
        }

        [Service]
        public class PhoneNr : IntentService
        {
            private string ownNumber;
            public string getOwnNumber()
            {
                return (ownNumber);
            }

            protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
            {
                var telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
            ownNumber = telephonyManager.Line1Number;
            }


        }
    }
```

General part:

```
namespace Zum
{
    public interface IPersonalia
    {
        string getOwnNr();
    }
}
```

The test button with test label:

```
private void BtnTemporary_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                var Person = (Person)BindingContext;
                lblTemp.Text=DependencyService.Get<IPersonalia>().getOwnNr();

            }
        }
```